# Import results from complex SQL query into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, pandasql

So I have this query:

```
Select columnA, column B
into #tempTableA 
from table1

update #tempTableA tbA set #tempTableA.column1 = table2.columnB
from table2 tb2
where tb2.column1 = tbA.column2;

Select * from #tempTableA
```

I've tried using read_sql_query in order to import the result into dataframe, but either the error of 'Nonetype' appears or it will take forever to run (meaning it will not return the dataframe). I'm using Jupyter Notebook as the tool for this. Is there a way to import the result from SQL into the dataframe?

Comment: What result?  The query doesn't return anything.

Comment: So how could I make it return result? I also tried select statement at the end, but it doesn’t work

Comment: Would it not be easier to import table1 directly into a pandas data frame and then do the updates in the Python script instead?

Comment: I think it would be easier. However, the query here is just a sample of a bigger query that has more update and insert statements, temporary table and temporary procedure. So I’m wondering if there is something we can do to wrap it up so that it could return results into the data frame?

Comment: @DatNguyen Did you find a solution to your question?

Comment: Could you share the solution?